# How to update a column in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra. I'm not getting how to update a particular column in Cassandra related to a particular user.

For example I want to update the location of a user in a user column family.

Comment: this information is insufficient. What have your read, what have you tried, what is your structure.. etc?

Comment: Hi Bozho, for example i want to update location of user in User columnfamily...how can i do that...

Comment: @saggy please edit your question, put your comment into it and try to provide all information necessary to answer. In the current form, the question is not answerable.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the thrift API, there is no difference between update and insert. It's the same API call.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between insert/update in cassandra (as Pranab said).

Now to address you example of a user... I'm assuming you have a row per user, and columns for things such as name, email, location.

If you did two inserts

[pseudo-code]

```
insert('user-123', {'name': 'bob', 'email': 'bob@example.com'})
insert('user-123', {'location': 'nowheresville'}
```

[/pseudo-code]

you'll end up with a user-row that looks like this:

```
row-key: 'user-123'
row-value: {'name': 'bob', 'email': 'bob@example.com',
            'location': 'nowheresville'}
```

That should answer your question, but one other note of rows/columns in cassandra.  Since there are no locks places on the row, you should be careful about breaking your data apart like this.  If two people saved 'user-123' at the same time I *think* it's possible to have a row that is half what you wanted it to be and half what the other inserter of the data wanted to it be.

Because of this, it's generally a better idea to save all of the user's data in a single cell (serialized).

an alternate structure for this data could be:

```
row-key: 'nowheresville'
row-value: {'bob-123': serialized-bob-data}
serialized-bob-data: {'name': 'bob', 'email': 'bob@example.com'}
```